# routes in rails 3 .. basic routes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I m having a controller users in which there are three actions show, update and prepare and there respective views in views/users directory

Now when i am trying this:--

```
http://localhost:3000/users/prepare
```

I am getting an error

```
No route matches "/users/prepare"
```

can anybody explain me how to specify this routes in routes.rb for this.. I am a beginner for rails

```
  map.connect '/prepare', :controller => 'users', :action => 'prepare'
```

this is not working..

**EDIT**
Anybody who can help me pls.

Comment: what Rails version are you using? 2.x or 3?

Comment: @vlad.zloteanu i mentioned in the title rails 3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is a good read: [The Lowdown on Routes in Rails 3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the rails3 way:

```
resources :users do
  get :prepare, :on => :member
end
```

Show and update are already covered by just mapping it as a resource.

Comment: he means `get :prepare, :on => :collection`